# Response status is 500 for swagger appears once HttpGet for a specific object is implemented

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, http-get, webapi

I am learning how to create a WebApi utilizing C# to expand my code knowledge from just Java. I have created one with a List so far but I am attempting to use a Dictionary now. I have implemented a HttpGet with no problems

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Projections.Order> GetOrders()
{
 var data = repository.GetOrders().Values.Select( o => new Projections.Order(o));
 return data;
}
```

However once I have tried adding another HttpGet to search for a specific Order via an Id then I get the following message "response status is 500 /swagger/v1/swagger.json" The code I that causes the problem is:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Order GetOrder(Guid id)
{
 var data = repository.GetOrder(id);
 return data;
}
```

Additional information I can provide is my Dictionary and the two methods I am using to implement my HttpGets

```
public readonly Dictionary<int, Order> Data = new Dictionary<int, Order>()
{
  {0, new Order
   {
    CustomerName = "Trey",
    OrderId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    OrderType = OrderType.Standard,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 4, 5),
    CreatedByUserName = "Matt"
    }
   }
};

public Dictionary<int, Order> GetOrders()
{
 return Data;
}

public Order GetOrder(Guid id)
{
 Order order = null;
 foreach( var pair in Data )
 {
  if(pair.Value.OrderId == id)
  {
   order = pair.Value;
   break;
  }
 }
return order;
}
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the return. If I make the code look like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public void GetOrder(Guid id)
{
 var data = repository.GetOrder(id);
 //return data;
}
```

Then the error message won't appear.

Comment: A 500 response corresponds to an internal server error, so something within your internal logic (probably within your GetOrder) function is throwing an error. Can you put a few breakpoints in there to see what the internal error message is? Your console should also contain more info about the error.

Comment: I have put breakpoints in those methods as well as in Program.cs and Startup.cs. The breakpoints were hit after I had pressed F5. In the Output windows on Visual Studio Code I don't see anything that sticks out as an Error message in the Output. I see the 500 message only when when I go to https://localhost:[port]/swagger.

Comment: If you go Debug menu>>Windows>>Exceptions and tick on next to CLR, does VS pause as soon as an error occurs and give you some more detail about it?

Comment: As an aside, why use a dictionary at all if you're only going to loop through it. I'd expect the key to be the Guid

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the tip about the Dictionary. They are something I don't really use very often. I believe I did finally find the issue and I thank you. I was doing through the Debug Window and found the lines: 
 ---> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate schema for type - API.Models.Order. See inner exception
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$Order" for type "$API.Models.Order". The same schemaId is already used for type "$API.Projections.Order"

Comment: Looks like I made a mistake in naming 2 .cs files the same. I'm assuming Swagger can't really tell the difference I should try clarifying.

Comment: Order is indeed a fairly bland name..

Comment: @CaiusJard it did look like I could tag you in my answer but I do give you the credit for helping me by giving me a push to look at the Debug one more time. Also for the nice helpful tip about handling the Guid as a Key. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. Thank you to those that pushed me to look closer at the Debug Window. Although I saw no traditional "error color" message there was a message hidden in there telling me that what CS file I was referencing was ambiguous. I rewrote the code to reference either specifically "API.Models.Order" or "API.Projections.Order".